# Email template referencer

Tags: c#, comparative-review

Which is best practice for creating an enum-like lookup for templates? I enjoy being able to bring up my templates with VS IntelliSense so either works for me.

Option 1 (`enum`/`Dictionary` combo):

```
public enum Template
{
    AccountInformation = 1,
    Registration = 2,
    Signed = 3
}
static readonly IDictionary<Template, String> TemplateData = new Dictionary<Template, String>()
{
    {Template.AccountInformation, "accountinfo.txt"},
    {Template.Registration, "registration.txt"},
    {Template.Signed, "signed.txt"}
};
```

Option 2 (`static` class):

```
public static class Template
{
    public static String AccountInformation = "accountinfo.txt";
    public static String Registration = "registration.txt";
    public static String Signed = "signed.txt";
}
```

Comment: Option #1, but make the declaration `static readonly IDictionary<>`

Comment: I have fixed the declaration, this is the option I have initially chosen so it is good to know that I may have picked  the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public enum Template
{
    [StringValue("accountinfo.txt")]
    AccountInformation = 1,
    [StringValue("registration.txt")]
    Registration = 2,
    [StringValue("signed.txt")]
    Signed = 3
}
```

For more information: [String Enumerations in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11130/String-Enumerations-in-C)

Otherwise, I prefer your second option.

Comment: Additionally I find you should name the enum EmailTemplate and its values AccountInformationEmail or RegistrationEmail or SignedEmail.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on the logical meaning of the string.

If there is a fixed number of valid values, then you should use your first option, use the enum almost everywhere, and convert to `string` using the dictionaly at the last possible place. (By “fixed” I mean that the string can have only a small fixed set of values in each version of the application, but the set of possible values may change between versions.)

On the other hand, if the values represent some set of “usual” values, but other values are also a possibility (e.g. a user-specified file name), the I would use option 2.